# JAWS screen reader scrolls the FireFox page up/down with arrow keys instead of navigating between elements

Tags: accessibility, mozilla, jaws-screen-reader

I'm using JAWS 2022 for a11y testing. Everything works fine on Chrome and worked fine for a while on FireFox, too, until recently. Suddenly I can't navigate between the elements using the arrow keys. Using up and down keys will scroll the page up and down. I can somewhat navigate using Tab but that's not enough. Caret browsing is off. Restarting JAWS and refreshing the page doesn't help. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess you are referring to form controls, and navigation in JAWS Form Mode?

Comment: @Andy no, there are no forms on the page. I'm trying to navigate between the elements on a regular web page.

Comment: While NVDA lets me start and stop NVDA as many times as I want and it still works with Firefox, JAWS, on the other hand, often behaves like you're describing and I have to kill Firefox, start JAWS, then start Firefox.  It usually works for a while, as you said, but then stops working again at some point.  But starting Firefox **after** JAWS starts usually fixes it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though the JAWS virtual cursor has been turned off. Try pressing Insert+Z and it should announce "JAWS virtual cursor on", then try arrowing again.

Comment: Didn't help. Thanks for suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
JAWS 2021.2111.13 ILM and Firefox 104.0.1

In my case also the headings shortcut (H), buttons (B), lists (L), and all the other shortcuts don't work.

I've found a workaround removing checks `Use recommended performance settings` and `Use hardware acceleration when available` in Firefox Settings > Hardware

And also starting JAWS before Firefox.

it's a strange problem, which doesn't always happen.

I hope someone knows the REAL solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation listed here didn't help me when i ran into this issue with JAWS 23 and FF 115 today. What did help was to go in the FF settings and checking the checkbox labeled "Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages" in the browsing section.